# Android: Register a BroadcastReceiver from my activity and keep it active while my app is not running

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

can i register a BroadcastReceiver from my activity but keep it active while the app is not running? (obviously if the user sets that wants this on my app settings)

This way i think to reduce cpu load if user decide of deactivate my app without uninstall it, it's possible?

Thank's

Valerio

Answer (score 3):

> Hi, can i register a BroadcastReceiver from my activity but keep it active while the app is not running? (obviously if the user sets that wants this on my app settings)

No. However, you can put a `BroadcastReceiver` in your manifest, which will allow it to get control when the rest of your app is not running. If you want the user to be able to enable or disable this, you can use `PackageManager` to enable or disable your receiver.

Comment: I was thinking also that i can register the broadcast receiver in to a service, I still use it :)

Comment: @Skatephone: Please please please please do NOT leave a service running just to try to have a `BroadcastReceiver` running. First, it won't work, as Android will kill off your service eventually as being a waste of space. Second, users will attack you with task killers and give you poor Market ratings, because you are taking up RAM. If you need a `BroadcastReceiver` during the natural lifetime of an activity or service, using `registerReceiver()` is perfectly reasonable. However, the natural lifetime of a service is never "forever".

Comment: Is not as you are thinking, my service will start from a first broadcast receiver when a call starts and it will stop wen the call ends :)

Comment: The problem was that I understand that the registerReceiver() metodh is valid only while my app is running

Comment: @Skatephone: I believe you are correct. Hence, use a manifest-registered `BroadcastReceiver`, which can start and stop your service on relevant broadcasts.

Comment: Yes, the only doubt was if there is a way to deregister my broadcast if the user decide to deacticate my program :)